# How to alias commands after multi-hop SSH connection within the same alias

Tags: ssh, alias, bashrc

I try to alias to multi-hop SSHing and  to put some additional  commands  to this alias after  login  to the remote machine. I have  already working alias to ssh-ing to remote machine

alias comandname='ssh -t -t  -X  '\''login@machine1'\'' exec  "ssh  -X  '\''login@machine2'\''"'

but I don't how to put command  to run on the machine2. I also tried to put something into .bashrc on machine2 (it didn't work) but I would like to know more general solution to have several different command under different aliases. The  simple example command would be cd to specific folder on machine 2 from this alias.

Answer (score 2):

I've had more success with adding configuration stanza's to $HOME/.ssh/config

eg.

```
Host machine2-via-machine1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q machine1 -W machine2:22
```

then you should be able to

```
ssh machine2-via-machine1
```

instead of an shell alias.

Since ssh no understands the multihop arrangement ; additional arguments on the command line are processed you might and host key validation seems to be better too.

Comment: Use `-W` switch to `ssh` instead of `nc`.

Comment: @Jakuje That is better. I've edited my answer to include your suggestion thanks.